# How to access DisplayName annotation within loop rather than from Model in Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is probably a basic question, but I am currently missing the light on this one.

I usually use :

```
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.myProperty)
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.myProperty)
```

Which displays the `DisplayName` annotation, from the View Model, for the property. Also `DisplayFor` displays the value.

However what if I want to iterate through a Model List and then do the same?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.myPropertyList)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(item=>item.myProperty) //No longer works
  @Html.DisplayFor(item=>item.myProperty) // No Longer works.
}
```

What should the code be in the `foreach` loop to pickup the Property `DisplayName` and value.

I realise that the following will work for displaying the value:

```
@item.myProperty
```

EDIT:

Answer seems to be:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem=>item.myProperty)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.myProperty)
```

Found by helpers here and me.... team effort.... Thanks

Comment: Hi. What is the model of the view?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.myProperty)
```

Comment: DisplayFor works but not LabelFor... like this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check with the below one

```
<div>
        <table border="1" class="col-md-12 text-center table-font table-hover table-striped table" id="tblTemp">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" style="color:#000;">
                        My Property For Label
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="color:#000;">
                        My Property For Textbox
                    </th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

     @foreach (var item in Model.myPropertyList)
     {
       <tr>
           <td class="text-left">
               @Html.LabelFor(modelItem=>item.myProperty) //Should work
           </td>
           <td class="text-left">
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.myProperty) // Should work
           </td>
        </tr>
      }
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still getting a problem here. How could I assign the value of the DisplayName into a variable, Just trying to debug this.

Comment: Type is LabelFor<ViewModel,string> not type of "Item" in ForEach. Thks for help thus far

Comment: DisplayFor works but not LabelFor... like this. Any ideas? Thanks. Basically I want to Display the Annotation value for "DisplayName" as one would normally do in a form

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem=>item.myProperty)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.myProperty)
```